# Best way to integrate a react fuse template in php codeigniter

Tags: php, reactjs, codeigniter, configuration, integration

We have an app using the Codeigniter framework, and we are trying to connect a Fuse React Template [Fuse React](http://react-material.fusetheme.com/documentation/configuration/routing) to be used as the view of the application.

Which way would be the best way to integrate the react build into the php code base?

We first thought that it would be easy to just use a react_view_controller. Similar to this:
[How to integrate Reactjs frontend with php codeigniter application on apache server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041699/how-to-integrate-reactjs-frontend-with-php-codeigniter-application-on-apache-ser)

but it seemed confusing to import the files into a script one by one since they are coming  from a well structured template.

Then we thought we will build out the production build and mount that into the php codebase.
How do we configure php to look at the react-build files?

Anyone have any resources I could look up?